# How to dynamically load EJBs with web service interfaces as plugins?

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, jboss, ejb

I have a Web application that has an optional SOAP interface (implemented as a bunch of EJBs) to its data. The main application and SOAP interface were separated, sharing only database access code, but recently they were integrated as one application (the SOAP interface was packaged as a JAR that was added to the main application's depencencies). Both are hosted on a JBoss server.

The solution works, but our application uses a modular plugin interface that allows toggling specific features on and off from the app's user interface, using Maven to locate the plugins. The plugins are then loaded using a `URLClassLoader` with the application's default class loader as the parent, and registered to our generic page dispatcher servlet that's mapped to `*.page`:

```
<!-- from web.xml -->
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcer</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.page</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the current solution, the EJBs are exposed using `web.xml`:

```
<!-- the very same web.xml -->
<servlet>
  <display-name>BaseService</display-name>
  <servlet-name>BaseService</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>ourapp.services.BaseService</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>BaseService</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/services/Base/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Of course when the EJB:s are loaded at runtime, we can't specify them in advance, so:

**How can I load EJB:s from a JAR and expose them as web services at runtime?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your web app to EJB jars and WAR and deploy/redeploy.
Then in your app, you may check for the availability of particular services.

If you use JBoss AS 7, then you could leverage the Management API to deploy/undeploy the plugin EJB jars.
See here:

- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/The+native+management+API
- https://community.jboss.org/thread/155937
- [Jboss as 7 deploy using HTTP managment api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395271/jboss-as-7-deploy-using-http-managment-api)

Comment: We split those two earlier, but it conflicted with the plugin system and caused issues with Hibernate Search. The forum thread looked promising, I'll check those out.

Answer (score 1):

There are no standard APIs to dynamically load EJBs (I'm not even aware of any vendor APIs that allow this).  In general, EE deployment is focused on up-front packaging that enables the application server to introspect your application and perform various preparations and optimizations.